# How to import npm scoped packages with @ in Deno?

Tags: javascript, github, npm, deno

I am trying to import @whiskeysockets/baileys in Deno like this:

```
import * as a from "npm:@whiskeysockets/baileys";
console.log(a);
```

But it's showing the following error when I try to run `deno run main.ts`:

```
error: Error in @whiskeysockets/baileys@6.6.0 parsing version requirement for dependency: libsignal@github:adiwajshing/libsignal-node

Invalid npm version requirement. Unexpected character.
  github:adiwajshing/libsignal-node
  ~

Caused by:
    0: Invalid npm version requirement. Unexpected character.
         github:adiwajshing/libsignal-node
         ~
    1: Unexpected character.
         github:adiwajshing/libsignal-node
```

I'm guessing that it's interpreting 'whiskeysockets' as version number instead of the scope namespace since it's followed by '@'? Not sure. How can I fix this and import it properly?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this. One is using esm.sh

```
import * as a from "https://esm.sh/@whiskeysockets/baileys";
```

This is how I fetch GitHub repositories and write them to a `node_modules` folder in the current working directory, which you can do for the source code of the project in your question

```
async function installRepositoryFromGitHubToNodeModules(url) {
  return new Deno.Command("/bin/sh", {
    /*
    cd node_modules/.deno
    git clone "$1"
    cd ..
    ln -s  "`pwd`/.deno/$2" "`pwd`"
  */
    args: [
      "install_from_github.sh",
      url,
      url.split("/").pop(),
    ],
  }).output();
}

const { code, stdout, stderr } = await installRepositoryFromGitHubToNodeModules(
  "https://github.com/guest271314/wbn-sign-webcrypto",
);

console.log([stdout, stderr].map((result) => decoder.decode(result)));
```

Comment: It looks like you are going to have to deal with the the fact the imported script refers to a `document` in https://esm.sh/v135/libsignal@2.0.1/denonext/libsignal.mjs:12:3718.